# Import in python, two modules sharing common resource

Tags: python, import

For instance, consider 3 modules namely "apple", "orange" and "fruit". Module "apple" imports "orange" and "fruit". Module "orange" imports "fruit" only. Since "fruit" is common for both, could this be done in a different way? Is this inefficient in terms of memory usage and speed?

I wonder how this is done in professionally distributed packages. Say, if a standard library module (viz. httplib) is needed throughout various modules that has GUI code and other complicated stuff. importing this module in every GUI file would be impractical, wouldn't it?

Comment: Python automatically addresses this issue.  Modules are only imported the first time.  Subsequent requests to the same module name are handled by returning the previously loaded module.

Comment: always import anything you use in the file ...

Comment: So if there are 10 files; file 1 imports file2, 2 imports 3 etc... and all these import httplib, it wouldn't effect efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules that are imported more than one are generally only initialized **once** and the namespace is introduced into the scope of the module.  So in your example above there is one class fruit and the two classes that inherit from it and if you were to introduce 3 varieties of apple there would still only be one underlying fruit class.

This **is** how professional packages do it.  In other languages like C/C++ you need to use wards to prevent multiple imports python does if for you.